# Recursion Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

Keep getting an error when I run the following.
Any help greatly appreciated.

John

```
    var power = function (base, exponent){
        if (exponent === 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else () {
            return base * power(base, exponent-1);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You should better check for `exponent <= 0`.

Comment: Your error is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: @LuchianGrigore's answer is quite right and simple. Note that Firebug, although not installed by default is a gold-worthy tool. Many times it saved me  from losing hours of debugging JS line-by-line... You should consider installing it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis after the `else`:

```
var power = function (base, exponent){
    if (exponent === 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {  // <--- extra parenthesis here
        return base * power(base, exponent-1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**check out this you have a typo**

```
var power = function (base, exponent){
        if (exponent === 0){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return base * power(base, exponent-1);
        }
    };
```